# Why does this line of code cause a computer to crash?

Tags: c++, c, memory

Why does this line of code cause the computer to crash? What happens on memory-specific level?

```
for(int *p=0; ;*(p++)=0)
    ;
```

I have found the "answer" on Everything2, but I want a specific technical answer.

Comment: it is undefined behaviour which means anything can happen, including explode your computer

Comment: Bryan Chen, can you elaborate and let me know exactly *why* that would cause "anything to happen"?

Comment: @EthanBarron this is the definition of UB. It's Undefined Behavior, a flying pig could appear (although I deem it unlikely)

Comment: What kind of "computer"? I can't imagine that any modern computer/OS would crash because of this code. Your program will crash, but the computer won't.

Comment: @AndreyT As an aside, note that for the most popular OS of the 1980's and early 90's, MSDOS, uninitialized pointers would and could indeed cause the computer to reboot.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Overriding interrupt vector area residing at low addresses could indeed easily cause a reboot. This is why I'm asking what kind of hardware/OS platform the OP is using.

Comment: Anyone claiming that the code in question *definitely* tries to access memory is formally wrong. C++ describes an abstract machine, and the *full* behaviour of the program is undefined if the abstract machine would execute that line. An implementation could ignore that line (and those around it) as unreachable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code simply formally sets an integer pointer to null, then writes to the integer pointed by it a 0 and increments the pointer, looping forever.

The null pointer is not pointing to anything, so writing a 0 to it is undefined behavior (i.e. the standard doesn't say what should happen). Also you're not allowed to use pointer arithmetic outside arrays and so even just the increment is also undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior means that the compiler and library authors don't need to care at all about these cases and still the system is a valid C/C++ implementation. If a programmer does anything classified as undefined behavior then whatever happens happens and s/he cannot blame compiler and library authors. A programmer entering the undefined behavior realm cannot expect an error message or a crash, but cannot complain if getting one (even one million executed instructions later).

On systems where the null pointer is represented as zeros and there is no support for memory protection the effect or such a loop could be of starting wiping all the addressable memory, until some vital part of memory like an interrupt table is corrupted or until the code writes zeros on the code itself, self-destroying. On other systems with memory protection (most common desktop systems today) execution may instead simply stop at the very first write operation.

Comment: "On systems where the null pointer is represented as zeros ...  On **other** systems execution may simply stop at the very first write operation." -- On the majority of systems, a null point is represented as zeros **and** the program will get a segmentation fault on the first write,

Comment: @JimBalter: Thanks. That "other" was deceiving.

Answer (score 4):

Undoubtedly, the cause of the problem is that `p` has not been assigned a reasonable address.

By not properly initializing a pointer before writing to where it points, it is probably going to do *Bad Things*™.

It could merely segfault, or it could overwrite something important, like the function's return address where a segfault wouldn't occur until the function attempts to return.

---

In the 1980s, a theoretician I worked with wrote a program for the 8086 to, once a second, write one word of random data at a randomly computed address.  The computer was a process controller with watchdog protection and various types of output.  The question was:  How long would the system run before it ceased usefully functioning?  The answer was ***hours and hours***!  This was a vivid demonstration that most of memory is rarely accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the '80s info. Very intriguing. But what about address "0"? Is that something that is ever, or *even* rarely, accessed?

Comment: @EthanBarron:  In virtual address spaces, addresses below 1000 or 100000 or so are unmapped to *cause* a segfault since NULL pointers are such a common programming bug.  In non-virtual environments, many if not most CPU architectures have important system information near address zero, usually interrupt vectors.  Overwriting those usually causes system crashes or worse.

Comment: Wally, makes complete sense to me. You've been very informative, and I  very much appreciate your contribution to my own personal education. Great answer!

Comment: Wally, again, you're awesome, but somehow I must've missed 6502's answer, and I think that his answer is a good one (not that yours isn't). I wish I could accept both, but let's let you have the votes, and him have the question :P

Thanks again, so much!

Answer (score 1):

It *may* cause an OS to crash, or it may do any number of other things.  You are invoking undefined behavior. You don't own the memory at address `0` and you don't own the memory past it.  You're just trouncing on memory that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: Good answer, too. Not quite as technical as I was hoping but very much appreciate your effort! Thanks :)

Comment: @EthanBarron: I'm not sure what more you were after.  On most modern OS's you will not crash anything (except for your program) because you do not have the privilege of writing to whichever memory address you like.  A segfault will be issued and your program will go down. Now... on non-mainstream OS's, perhaps something like an embedded system or a device driver, you can overwrite data needed by the OS or another program and cause havoc.

Comment: good to hear back from you. I was genuinely just curious. It is not a seriously important question (as in, no systems *or* programs are going to crash as a result). I was more intrigued by the actual technicalities of it. It isn't that I had a program/system crash, but that someone posed the question to me, and I wanted to know the answer. Thanks again, Ed!

Answer (score 0):

It works by overwriting all the memory at all the addresses, starting from 0 and going upwards. Eventually it will overwrite something important.

On any modern system, this will only crash your program, not the entire computer. CPUs designed since, oh, 1985 or so, have this feature called *virtual memory* which allows the OS to redirect your program's memory addresses. Most addresses aren't directed anywhere at all, which means trying to access them will just crash your program - and the ones that are directed somewhere will be directed to memory that is allocated to your program, so you can only crash your own program by messing with them.

On much older systems (older than 1985, remember!), there was no such protection and this loop could access memory addresses allocated to other programs and the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is not necessary to explain what's wrong. We can simply look at only the first iteration.

```
int *p = 0; // Declare a null pointer
*p = 0;     // Write to null pointer, causing UB
```

The second line is causing undefined behavior, since that's what happens when you write to a null pointer.